# how to catch unhandled exception in C++ code

Tags: c++, string, exception, visual-c++, unhandled-exception

```
#define MAX 260 
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
std::wstring getDirectory()
{
  wchar_t Ext[MAX] = L"body.html";
  wchar_t Buffer[MAX] = L"";

  try
  {
    auto val = L"C:\\ProgramData\\Production\\00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\\111111111111\\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.";
    wcscpy_s(Buffer, val);
    
    wcscat_s(Buffer, Ext);

    return std::wstring(Buffer);
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    std::cout << "exception raised." << std::endl;
    throw std::exception("Failed to create Directory");
  }
}
```

In this example, the call of `wcscat_s(Buffer, Ext);` generate an unhandled exception because of the invalid parameter 'Buffer' that the size exceeded the max size tolerated (260 caracters) .
The use of try .. catch didn't catch the unhandled exceptions from the C library. Is there a way to throw the exception ? thanks

Comment: OT: `#define MAX 260` is what you want.

Comment: explicitly compare `strlen(val) < MAX` ?

Comment: There are no exceptions in C. `wcscpy_s` is a C function and can't throw an exception.

Comment: @uben yes i think about using strlen , but is there a pretty way to catch all exceptions that may occur from the use of wcscat_s

Comment: better don't mix C and C++. Contrary to common believe it isnt the most simple thing to do (yes it is possible and it isnt the most complicated thing to do, but why do it when you do not need to?)

Comment: @ThomasSablik thanks, so i should use wcslen before wcscpy_s

Comment: Why not use `std::wstring`s all the way instead? Copying strings becomes very easy.

Comment: whats wrong with `return L"C:\\ProgramData\\Product....` ? You do not need C functions to copy or create C++ strings

Comment: Please note that you should have included a [mcve] in the question. The code you posted does not have an unhandled exception at runtime, because it does not compile: https://godbolt.org/z/5b8WWY

Comment: to append to a C++ string you can use `+`

Comment: The right way to go about this is to make sure the "exception" never occurs in the first place. Don't try to catch access violations, it's not the way.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I suspect OP is encountering an SEH "exception", which is Window's equivalent of signals.

Comment: @Quentin I added the visual-c++ tag. It's a Windows/MSVC specific problem.

Comment: @idclev463035818 even if i use wstring , i need to check the size because the max directory length on windows is 260

Comment: Which of these functions throws something similar to an exception? I can't find anything in the documentation: [wcscpy_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s?view=msvc-160), [wcscat_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcat-s-wcscat-s-mbscat-s?view=msvc-160) These functions shouldn't throw anything. They should return an error code.

Comment: @ThomasSablik the code is bloqued in wcscat_s and i get the exception : Unhandled exception at 0x0F2EE906 (ucrtbased.dll) An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.
And that's the exception i want to throw

Comment: The problem here is that you didn't mention that this is a MSVC specific question. MS has implemented templated C++ versions of  `wcscpy_s` and `wcscat_s` with different parameters. Many people here, me included, are not using MSVC and were not aware about it and are not able to reproduce the problem. Most comments here regarding these two functions are wrong. It's possible that these functions throw but I can't find documentation about it.

Comment: you can check the size via the strings `size` or `length` method. C doesnt have them, thats why C has other ways

Comment: Runtime errors often get reported as "exceptions", but unless there is a `throw` somewhere, such an "exception" is not a C++ exception. So you can't catch it.